# "securityd: keychain reference in server mode" in console

Tags: security, keychain, adobe, adobe-photoshop

I am experiencing a strange issue when starting **Adobe Creative Cloud 2017.3** applications (Photoshop, Illustrator,...). The applications hang the system completely for a minute or two (50% System-level load across all 8-cores, reported by iStat) and there are many `securityd` messages "`keychain reference in server mode`" (700 in quick succession when app is starting up) in console. So it seems, there is something wrong with either keychain or the apps. This happens on my Mac Pro, but does not on Macbook Pro, both having the most recent macOS and the same settings.

I've traced the message to https://opensource.apple.com/source/libsecurity_keychain/libsecurity_keychain-55035/lib/StorageManager.cpp but I have no idea, what does it tie to, as `gServerMode` seems to be some global constant set via `SecKeychainSetServerMode()` function in https://opensource.apple.com/source/Security/Security-57336.1.9/OSX/libsecurity_keychain/lib/SecKeychain.cpp.

But I have no idea, if there is something I could do to mitigate the issue (i.e. if it is damaged keychain or something like that).